# ODI Sql Spool with GetOption of Query Separator

Tags: oracle11g, separator, data-integration, oracle-data-integrator

Hello .
I need to run a select using a separator for the fields to make a sql spool WHEN use static character ;

So I do:
`select < % = odiRef.getColList ( " " , " [ EXPRESSION ] ',' || ' , ' || " , " " , " " ) % > from < % = snpRef.getFrom ( ) % >`

Now if I try to replace ' || ' , ' || " with a odiRef.getOption not working .

Some of you have already had a similar problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

`select <%=odiRef.getColList("", "[EXPRESSION]", **"||'"` `+` `odiRef.getUserExit("option_name")` `+` `"'||"**, "", "")%>` from `<%=snpRef.getFrom()%>`